# Anti Merging Large DataSets with Multiple Conditions

Tags: r, datatable, merge

2Suppose I have two data frames:

```
A <- data.frame(X1=c(1,2,3,4,5), X2=c(3,3,4,4,6), X3=c(3,2,14,5,4))
B <- data.frame(X1=c(1,3,5), X2=c(3,4,6))
```

I want to merge the two so that the when X1 and X2 in A are in a row in B, then those entire rows (with all columns) are returned from A. I have tried anti_join and merge, but the results are not working as planned and merge can not handle larger dataframes. I have also tried things with the data table package.
I would like the below dataframe to be returned or saved to a new object.

```
 C <- data.frame(X1=c(2,4), X2=c(3,4), X3=c(2,5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just do `A%>%anti_join(B, by = c("X1", "X2"))`? That way you have the `by` set to both X1 and X2, and you get all the outliers.

```
> A <- data.frame(X1=c(1,2,3,4,5), X2=c(3,3,4,4,6), X3=c(3,2,14,5,4))
> B <- data.frame(X1=c(1,3,5), X2=c(3,4,6))

> A%>%inner_join(B, by = c("X1", "X2"))
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  3  3
2  3  4 14
3  5  6  4


 > A%>%anti_join(B, by = c("X1", "X2"))
      X1 X2 X3
    1  2  3  2
    2  4  4  5
```